# I am using firebase for user auth but when i try to write a statement to show one page when its logged in and not i get a hook error and it wont show

Tags: javascript

all the imports and exports work.
I took them out of the post because my words to code ratio is too low to post.

```
...

function App() {

  const user = useAuthState(auth)

  
  return (
    <>
    <Chat />         
    if (user ?) {
      <Chat />
    } else {
      <SignIn />
    }
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I also tried using

```
...

function App() {

  const user = useAuthState(auth)

  
  return (
    <>
    {user ? <Chat /> : <SignIn />}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I still get a hook error.
yet when I remove `const [user] = useAuthState(auth)`
and replace `{user...}` with just `<Chat />` it works and shows up with no error

/>}

Answer (score 0):

there was a react error. I initialized two react apps in the beginning instead of one so it caused this hook error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).